# How to view / open .sof files in linux?

Tags: linux, file

I am trying to open *.sof file by using nedit / gedit , but it couldn't open. It seems that this file is binary file OR encrypted file.

Is there a way to view/open such kind of files in linux ?

Comment: You can seek on thematic forum: https://askubuntu.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

The sof file extension is associated with Quartus II, a development environment for Microsoft Windows operating system used to develop apps for FPGAs, SoCs, and CPLDs.

SOF file stands for Altera `SRAM Object File` that contains the data for configuring all SRAM-based Altera devices supported by the Quartus II software, using the Programmer.

So, .sof file is native to windows World. Wondering how you got that on your Linux System. Coming to your Question I think -

1. If it is really a `.sof` file, you can open it on some `Windows Machine in Notepad or Wordpad`.
2. It may be the case that file extension is misspelled. In that case you can check for other file extensions such as `.cof` or `.spf` or `.sod`
   You can refer to [this site](https://datatypes.net/open-sof-files) for further details.